# how to access patches programatically

Tags: 2010, powershell

I know I can access the SharePoint-buildversion using 
`(Get-SPFarm).buildversion` in PowerShell.

I also know that by accessing `/_admin/PatchStatus.aspx` from central administration I can view each installed hotfix (among other things).

Is there a way to programatically check (via server object model or PowerShell) whether a given hotfix (i.e. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2687339) is installed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information displayed on the Patch Status page uses a GridView control that is populated by the `Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.PatchStatusDataSourceView` object in the `Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Administration assembly` (`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\ADMINBIN\Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Administration.dll`).  This object is instantiated by the `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AdministrationDataSourceControl object in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`.

You could use that same data source to get your data.  For example:

```
var adminDataSourceControl = new AdministrationDataSourceControl() { ViewName = "PatchStatus" };
gridview.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
gridview.DataSource = adminDataSourceControl;
gridview.DataBind();
```

This does get the data, however the only caveat I found is that it needs to run under the Central Administration site.  You could dig further to figure out what resources you need to make it load elsewhere.

Comment: John, thanks for the answer. However I was thinking more along the lines of farm.GetAllPatches() :-) Using the DataSource-Control seems to be part of the UI-Controls and I'm not sure whether they can be used in PowerShell or featureRecievers.